# Flutter records return type issue

Tags: flutter, dart, record

This is the error I am currently dealing with:

```
A value of type '(Null, List<BoatModel>)' can't be returned from the method 'getBoatsFromOwnership' because it has a return type of 'Future<(Failure?, List<Boat>?)>'.
```

related to this code:

```dart
@override
  Future<(Failure?, List<Boat>?)> getBoatsFromOwnership(User user) async {
    try {
      return (null, await boatsDataSource.getBoatsFromOwnership(user.id));
    } on DatabaseException {
      return (DatabaseFailure(), null);
    }
  }
```

What confuses me is that this code, which does exactly the same, just for other data, works just fine:

```dart
@override
Future<(Failure?, List<Todo>?)> getTodos(Boat boat) async {
    try {
      return (null, await todosDataSource.getTodos(boat.id));
    } on DatabaseException {
      return (DatabaseFailure(), null);
    }
}
```

The same issue occurs here for `return (null, boats)`:

```dart
@override
Future<(Failure?, List<Boat>?)> getBoatsFromRelationships(User user, List<Relationship> relationships) async {
    final relationships = await relationshipsRepository.getRelationships(user);
    if (relationships.$1 == DatabaseFailure() || relationships.$2 == null) {
      return (DatabaseFailure(), null);
    }
    final relationshipsIds = relationships.$2!.map((relationship) => relationship.id).toList();
    try {
      final boats = await boatsDataSource.getBoats(
        userId: user.id,
        relationshipIds: relationshipsIds,
      );
      return (null, boats);
    } on DatabaseException {
      return (DatabaseFailure(), null);
    }
}
```

Also other parts are the same:

`class BoatModel extends Boat`

and

`class TodoModel extends Todo`

just like:

`Future<List<BoatModel>> getBoatsFromOwnership(String userId);`

and

`Future<List<TodoModel>> getTodos(String boatId);`

This of course uses Dart records, but I don't see the difference between my code for boats and for todos. If any other code is required to solve this issue, I am happy to provide more code snippets. I have no idea what is causing this issue. I could of course just map the types, but I think this issue shouldn't even exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the problem again today with a fresh mind, as I was wondering why the same code works for all the other models/entities, but not for the boats. I opened the classes side by side and compared and at some point realized that I had capitalization in imports at one point, so `/Boats/` instead of `/boats/`. After I corrected this, the problem was fixed. However, there was no hint that the imports were incorrect or missing. The reason for this mistake was that I copied the code and then replaced the relevant parts with find & replace. In doing so, I apparently made a capitalization mistake at one point. What do we learn from this? Don't copy and paste too much in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this has anything to do with `Record`-s. Seems like it's just how Dart's generics work with collections, meaning `List<BaseClass>` cannot store `DerivedClass` elements (without explicit casting) because the class hierarchy is not respected in this case.

Not sure though why your `getTodos` method works as expected.

Please see [this excellent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461895/9015579) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, definitely interesting what you wrote about the Dart generics. What was not logical for me was that it only didn't work with the boats, but with all other entities it did. So I looked at it again today with a fresh mind and found out that I had capitalized the imports at one point due to incorrect Copy > Paste > Replace. But this did not cause an error in the imports, only the one mentioned above. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It means precisely what it says.  You're trying to fit a BoatModel into the space provided by a Boat.  That won't work.

You seem to be mixing up Boat and BoatModel in your code.  Maybe you need to get rid of one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Getting rid of one of them won't work, as this is how clean architecture works... I understand the error so far, but I don't understand why it just does not work for Boats, but for all other entities/models of my app the same code works just fine.